# Cannot access page on localhost PHP Yosemite

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

I have a folder called PHP and its structure is as such:

```
+ PHP
  + Source
    + Chapter01
      + test.html
      + test.php
    + Chapter02
```

Now, I created a symlink in /Library/WebServer/Library called MyPHP to the PHP folder.

When i type in http://localhost/PHP/Source/Chapter01/test.html, it says:

You don't have permission to access /PHP/Source/Chapter01/test.html on this server.

So, I went to httpd.conf and added Require all granted as such:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But it still doesn't solve the problem! Help!

Comment: You need to give the PHP folder permissions so that other system users can access it. Do so recursively.

Comment: ^ 1) the symlink must be absolute path; 2) any directory in the tree of linked path must grant execution permission for apache user; 3) if 1 and 2 doesn't resolve your problem, you can try to add ad alias in apache config file (see [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/symlink-alias-folder/))

Comment: ... otherwise, the shorter solution is to invert link and linked: put original directory into apache Document Root and add a symlink in your actual 'PHP' parent directory

Comment: @Xorifelse I gave the PHP folder permissions with chmod 777 but no luck....still shows the same error.

Comment: @fusion3k I went for the shortcut you proposed. Much easier! And it works now,